# Zeppelin fail to z.show() pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, apache-zeppelin

According to the [docs](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.6.2/interpreter/python.html#pandas-integration), `DataFrame`s are displayed nicely by Zeppelin if I just do:

```
import pandas as pd
rates = pd.read_csv("bank.csv", sep=";")
z.show(rates)
```

But I trying the same wity my `DataFrame`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
    ('a', 'b') : {'value': 1}
}, orient='index')
z.show(df)
```

it gives:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 27, in show
  File "<stdin>", line 43, in show_dataframe
TypeError: string argument expected, got 'numpy.int64'
```

I thought it was a problem with Multilevel Indexes, but even after using `df.reset_index()` I can't make it work.

**UPDATE**

I can also reproduce this with a csv like

```
id,name,score
a,b,1.1
```

and using the `read_csv` method. If I drop the `score` column, the `z.show` works.

Is this a known issue? Is there a workaround? Or is it my mistake? I'm using Zeppelin version 0.6.2.

Comment: Does the example with read_csv work for you? Also, could you update the post with content of `./logs/zeppelin-interpreter-python-<username>-<hostname>.log` Have tried your example locally and could not reproduce the issue

Comment: I have a csv with a few lines like `some-string-id,some name,1.11111`, and it also fails. Interestingly, if I use the wrong separator, it loads all lines as a single column but raises no exceptions. Also, this error creates no log entries.

Comment: And which OS and version of Apache Zeppelin are you using? Python interpreter being improved a lot recently, so build from latest master is recommended

Comment: 0.6.2 on Ubuntu 16.04. I'll try the 0.7.0 snapshot soon.

Comment: FWIW, this works as designed on version 0.8.0